# Why all the jobs running on the single taskmanger?

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

[image]

I have a standalone flink cluster runs on a single node with two taskmangers.

After I start 35 jobs, I found that all the jobs runs on one of the taskmanagers.
There is no task running on another taskmanger.

I don't know what went wrong.

Comment: What version of Flink are you running? And what's the parallelism for these 35 jobs?

Comment: @kkrugler Flink version is 1.8.1 and each job takes one slot (1 parallelism).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLINK-12122. I think this issue is impacting your jobs. You can try either upgrading to Flink 1.9.2, or setting `cluster.evenly-spread-out-slots: true` in the `flink-conf.yaml`